# Matching Title Strings with Filenames

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to loop through a directory of image files and match the file's name to corresponding title string so that the path can be inserted into a database. What i have below works for about 90% of the files, but my string cleaning method is imperfect. Im looking for a smarter way of doing this. Thanks for your time.

filename example : `"2020_Super_Baseball_usa.jpg"`
title string example : `"2020 Super Baseball"`

```
def string_cleaner(string_one):
'''filter non alpha chars from filename'''

    filter_by= ":*/?-_.,'!'"
    new_string= ""

    for char in filter_by:
        for letter in string_one:
            if letter == char:
                if new_string == "":
                    new_string = string_one.replace(char, "")    
                else:
                    new_string = new_string.replace(char, "")

    return new_string

def matcher(string):
'''matches title string to filename and returns full path'''

    temp_path = ""
    tempfilename = ""
    path = "C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\pyscripts\\web- scraping\\SNES_DB_Scrape\\snes\\"
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        tempfilename = string_cleaner(file[:-7]).lower().lstrip().rstrip()
        if string.lower().lstrip() == tempfilename :
            temp_path = os.path.join(path, file)

    return temp_path 

for name in nameList:
    path = matcher(name)
    print("Name is: " + name + '\n' + "path is : " + path)
```

Answer (score 0):

considering your `filename` and `title` example, you can try below code:

```
filename = "2020_Super_Baseball_usa.jpg"
title = "2020 Super Baseball"

def string_cleaner(string_one):
    '''filter non alpha chars from filename'''

    new_string = ""
    for char in string_one:
        if char.isalnum():  #checking if string_one character if alphanumeric
            new_string = new_string + char  
        elif char == '_':
            new_string = new_string + " "

    return new_string

temp = string_cleaner(filename[:-7])

#print(temp)  #check output of string_cleaner function

if temp.lower().lstrip().rstrip() == title.lower().lstrip():
    print("match")
```